# How to get a particular table column value in a datagrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, null, undefined

I need to add the following statement in the code. Basically I have a table with 3 rows and 4 columns. For the row `i`, I want to get the 3rd column values. So I used the following..

```
document.getElementById("dataGrid_minimum_value").offsetParent.childNodes[1].children[i].children[2].textContent;
```

Question is do I have to check for null or undefined to avoid JavaScript errors in above statement?

Comment: Did u mean by data grid : HTML Table ?

Comment: yea, data grid as in HTML table with rows and columns.

Comment: See my answer. There is a demo at last